# Hiding selected elements with no unique identifiers 

Tags: jquery, hide

Using my code example below, what I would like to do is keep the images in the first 2 list objects, but hide the images in objects 3 and 4.

Removing the image from the 4th object is simple enough, but how can i remove the image from the 3rd object while keeping the image on the 2nd object.

```
<ul id="list">
<li class="start"><img class="postImage" src="image1.png" /><p>Some text here</p></li>
<li><img class="postImage" src="image2.png" /><p>Some text here</p></li>
<li><img class="postImage" src="image3.png" /><p>Some text here</p></li>
<li class="end"><img class="postImage" src="image4.png" /><p>Some text here</p></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery's [`gt()` selector](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=gt-selector).

To hide the entire `li` associated with those images use:

```
$("#list li:gt(1)").hide ();
```

To hide just the images use:

```
$("#list li:gt(1) img").hide ();
```

[**See it in action at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/uCFQ4/14/)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [:nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) JQuery selector.

```
$('#list li img:nth-child(4)').hide();
$('#list li img:nth-child(3)').hide();
// indexing from 1
```

or:

```
var imgs = $("#list li img");
imgs.eq(2).hide();
imgs.eq(3).hide();
// indexing from 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a very universal form, but does the job in your situation:

```
$("#list li img").eq(2).hide(); // hides the 3rd img
$("#list li img").eq(3).hide(); // hides the 4th img
```

A more abstract way, this would hide all img after the 2nd:

```
$("#list li img").each(function(i) {
    if (i > 1) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it with CSS, very simple

```
ul#list li img:nt-child(3) , ul#list li img:nt-child(4){
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: I think, @Timothy wants to do it in runtime. So, CSS will not help him.

Comment: Yes, this kind of CSS is hard to switch on and off at will.

Answer (score 0):

**Or the easiest way:**

```
$('#list li:eq(2) img').hide();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/4MCYM/1/)